# Update table with values from other table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a `table 1` where I have to replace some data in a column with data from a `table 2`.

```
Table 1

A       | B
-----------------------------
Test A1 | 123SOMETEXT
Test A2 | 456OTHERTEXT
Test A3 | 789MORETEXT


Table 2

B_old | B_new
-----------------------------
123   | ABC
456   | DEF
789   | GHI
```

Using this example I have to replace for example `123SOMETEXT` in column `B` of `table 1` with `ABCSOMETEXT` and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: Does your string always start with the 3 numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
update t1 set B = replace(B, cast(t2.B_old as varchar(10)), c2.B_new)
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.B like cast(t2.B_old as varchar(10)) + '%'
```